# Pop up dialog box is value is duplicate

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a google script that will scan through a specific column of one google sheet and check if any new additions are a duplicate. I have come up with the following, but it isn't working.

```
function hasDuplicates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Customer and form Details");
  var array = sheet.getRange('B2:B' + lastRow).getValues();
  var valuesSoFar = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        var value = array[i];
        if (value in valuesSoFar) {
          SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Hello, world!');
        }
      else{
        valuesSoFar.push(value);
      }
    }
}
```

As far as Im aware the above code creates an array called `array` and populates it with the specific range I am interested in. I then create a new, empty, array called `valuesSoFar`. The code then loops through the column and sequentially checks if that item has already been seen before, if so it gives you an alert. If not it adds it to the list of new items and keeps going.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit like you are using the online documentation code.

But the following assignment is missing:

```
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
```

or just replace `lastRow` with `sheet.getLastRow()`

**Update:**
I assume that the following solution should work if you actually have any duplicates in your column B:

```
function hasDuplicates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Customer and form Details");
  var array = sheet.getRange('B2:B' + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var valuesSoFar = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    var value = array[i][0];
    if (value in valuesSoFar) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Hello, world!');
    } else {
      valuesSoFar.push(value);
    }
  }
}
```

If it isn't working yet, I am sorry.

As long as you can not provide any information on what kind of error you are running into, I will not look into this anymore.

Comment: I have used aspects of the online documentation code but then adjusted it to my requirements. I have added the assignment, but still not working

Comment: Well have you done some kind of debugging? Any additionial information you could provide, other than "not working"? Are you sure, fore example that `sheet.getRange` returns a one-dimensional array?

Comment: How do you view the logs? Is it within google sheets or the script?

Comment: What about pressing F12 in the browser and writing some console.log statements into your snippet

Comment: put a `console.log(array[i])`inside the loop. I bet it will print out another array. depending on what it returns the proper assignemnt might look like this: `value = array[i][0]`

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see how to view the logs. I am running chrome on a mac

Comment: Try the proposed assignment: `value = array[i][0]` If you are unable to find the Developer Tools in your very own browser, I might nit be able to help you

Comment: Well it would probably be most helpful if you could help me figure out how to debug the script.

Comment: I do not have access to your data. I do not have access to your debug information. I am very sorry, but without you providing proper details there is nothing for me to do. You have to do at least part of the problem solving yourself.

Comment: I understand you need the debug information, I need it as well. Thats why I am asking if you can help me access it. With google sheets and google scripts I cannot work out how to find the console log. The IDE doesn't seem to be printing the logs, as least not where I expect it. I have tried looking at stackdriver logging but it is also not printing anything. If I could see that then I could see the two arrays and understand where Im going wrong